# Getting 401 with NTLM Authentication in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, httpclient, ntlm

I have tried every blog I could find about it . But I am not able to resolve status 401 with NTLM challenge.

So basically I need to get profile picture of an user which is hosted in company server.

When I hit the url in browser It prompts for username and password ,once I provide it I get the image.

But same I am not able to achieve in Xamarin.iOS

Below is the code snippet I am trying with .

```
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserName", "Password", "domain");

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials, UseDefaultCredentials = false };
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://mycustomUrl.net/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/eurn_martin_kremmer_MThumb.jpg");
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

Response I am getting is

```
    StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
SPRequestGuid: 5725369e-b047-40c5-d468-0417992ffab3
request-id: 5725369e-b047-40c5-d468-0417992ffab3
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 2
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4779
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2017 13:55:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0
}
```

Comment: exception is made for http calls , does https requires exception as well?

Comment: o yes, it's my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow , I didn't know the solution is as easy as pie , when you throw the same request with NSURLConnection.

here,

```
responseData = new NSMutableData();
request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(uri,NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, 6000);
request.HttpMethod = "GET";
 connection = new NSUrlConnection(request, this);
```

This works without hassle in Citrix MAM environment.

But to test it in simulator you need to handle challenge like below.

```
        public override void WillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge(NSUrlConnection connection, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(challenge.ProtectionSpace);

        if (challenge.PreviousFailureCount == 0 )
        {

            NSUrlCredential cred = new NSUrlCredential(this.myUserName, this.myPass, NSUrlCredentialPersistence.None);
            challenge.Sender.UseCredential(cred, challenge);
        }

    }
```